# TextFormField Border color does not change

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
    TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Ürün',
            labelStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
            prefixIcon: Icon(
              Icons.shopping_basket,
              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 121, 171, 245),
            ),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 3),
                gapPadding: 20.0),
          ),
        )
```

I'm trying to change the border color of OutlineInputBorder with this code but it doesn't change. It doesn't increase the width of the sides either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to just set `border`, but you should also set `enableBorder` and `focusedBorder` too, Set these in Theme data like this:

```
Theme(
            data: ThemeData(
              inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 3),
                  gapPadding: 20.0,
                ),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 3),
                  gapPadding: 20.0,
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 3),
                  gapPadding: 20.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            child: TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Ürün',
                labelStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                prefixIcon: Icon(
                  Icons.shopping_basket,
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 121, 171, 245),
                ),
                
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this decoration :

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: "Hint",
        counterText: "",
        isDense: true,
        alignLabelWithHint: true,
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.w, 2.h, 5.w, 1.7.h),
        enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).focusColor)),
        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, width: 0.5.w)),
        disabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).focusColor)),
      ),
```